# How to display returned data json to grid in firemonkey?

Tags: json, delphi, grid, firemonkey

I have received data from json web service with `RESTRequest` component 
but I do not know how I should display the returned data in a grid?

How can I use `RESTResponseDataSetAdapter` to improve this?

Comment: You know about Delphi's LiveBindings?

Comment: yes i know but cant use to solve this

Comment: Why do you think you can't?

Comment: tested
Because i don't know to use  RESTResponseDataSetAdapter component

Answer (score 2):

Try this - it took me about 15 minutes to get working

1. Open the RESTDemos in your Delphi install's Samples\Object Pascal\Database\RESTDemo
2. Drop a TStringGrid on the RHS of the the Delphi-Praxis tab (I chose this one because
   the URI on the `Fetch to DataSet` produces a 404 error).
3. If necessary, make the non-visual controls on the form visible.
4. Dbl-click BindingList and use the QuickBindings to add a `LinkGridToDataSource`. Set its
   `DataSource` to `ClientDataSet` and its `GridControl` to `StringGrid1`.  Thus will cause  `DBSourceDB1` to be created'.
5. Set the `Response` property of `RestReponseDataSetAdaptor` to `RESTResponse'.

Compile, run and click the `fetch list of forums` button.  You should see the StringGrid populates
from the  contents of `memo_ResponseData`

That should show you that LiveBindings can work with a RESTReponse to populate a grid.  The RESTDemos demo has a lot more things in it, but if this is your first experience of LiveBindings, you might want to backtrack and try setting up a simple test project which populates a TStringGrid and a few TEdits from a dataset of your own.

Comment: @NiliDelphi: Did this not answer your q?

Comment: tanks a lot
but after received data and display in grid with ClientDataSet , the persian data don't appears

Comment: like this : ÇÊÍÇÏíå ÝÑæÔäÏÇä æÔÇ æ ÎÑÇÒÇä ÇÑæãíå

Comment: But you didn't ask specifically about Persian data.  If you want to know about that, you'll need to ask about it in a new q.